# How to link SQL files in several TFS project?

Tags: version-control

In TFS2010, we have 3 team projects in the same TFS Collection:

- $Common
- $Project1\Database\Database.sln
- $Project2\Database\Name\Database.sln

The 2 projects need to use the same SQL files.
So I am considering to check-in these SQL files in a "Common" Team project.
But I don't know if it is the best solution to prevent duplicating these files, because it will be difficult to add a link to these SQL files in the 2 projects as they won't have the same relative path.

Is there another solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have in $Common a database project that can be referenced by the other two database projects:
$Common/CommonDatabase.sln

Comment: But a relative path will use to reference the project in $Common. A project has not the same path in several branches. This is my main problem.

Comment: You have differnt branches for $Project1 and $Project 2? And $commmon is not branched?

Comment: Using the workspace mappings in the build definition you may be able to maintain your relative path structure